# Covering the natural numbers with countable amount of disjunct sequences?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have got the following question:

Can you cover $\mathbb{N}$ with countable amount of arithmetic, **disjunct** sequences(their difference can't be the same, and $d>1$)?

I tried to do it with different differences, but the problem was that they met somewhere, so they couldn't be disjunct, because their difference is not alike, so I think the answer is no.

Any ideas? Thanks! :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by disjunct (and what $d$ is).

Comment: You can't find any element, which is part of more than 1 sequence, d is the difference. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

There is a well known solution:
$$\{2n, 4n+1,8n-1,\cdots \}$$
which are of the form $2^kn+u_k$ with $u_k$ is the residue closest to $0$ which has not been previously covered

All integers are of the form $2n$ or $2n+1$ so we choose the **first sequence** $2n$ we cover all even numbers. We will divide the set of odd numbers into two sequences those of the form $4n+1$ or $4n-1$ so the **second sequence** is $4n+1$ and we have to divide $4n-1$ into two parts those of the form $8n-1$ and those of the form $8n+3$, so the **third sequence** is $8n-1$ and we will divide $8n+3$ into two parts $16n+3$ and $16n-7$ and we take the **fourth sequence** to be $16n+3$ and we divide the rest into two parts $\cdots\cdots$

Comment: Can you tell how do you go further after $8n-1$, I can't really understand the logic. :)

Comment: no! $16n+1$ is already covered by $4n+1$, there is only two residues we did not cover mod $16$ which are $ $ and $16n-7$ and $16n+3$ so we take the closest to $0$ which is $16n+3$, and ther will be only two residus we did not cover $\mod 32$ and we take the closes to $0$

Comment: Very nice solution, thank you! :)